# Search results not opening

Tags: catalogsearch

I'm running into an issue with my product search. When a customer does a search, then clicks on an item, I wind up getting a 522 error. I'm currently using varnish, magento cache, and a CDN.

If I try to open the item from the category page, it opens just fine. But if I try to open it from a search results page, then it errors out.

I get this error using either Like or Fulltext.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be happening on all searches, just some. Having issues with both simple and configurable products.

Comment: Check your server error log(s). There should be something in there that can help out.

Comment: All I'm getting from the error log from Magento is this:  ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant boolean - assumed 'boolean'  in /home/MYDOMAIN/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1348

Comment: [Error codes in the 5xx range are all server related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error). If your web server (Apache/Nginx/etc.) error log doesn't have anything useful, check if the Varnish or Magento logs have any hints. Something, somewhere, is running into a server error, and there's no (good) way of finding it besides checking all possible logs. Varnish is definitely a big piece to check on, as it stands in front of your web server.